# How to use Polkadot.js API for governance proxy call correctly?

Tags: polkadot-js, proxy, transactions, api

I am trying to create [a JS code](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/js) to be able to vote using proxy account that has been given democracy permissions to stash account, so I would be able to vote using just my mobile phone instead of accessing my home setup for voting using just terminal.

[Substrate Extrinsics Docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics/#proxyreal-accountid32-force_proxy_type-optionnoderuntimeproxytype-call-call) instructs following
proxy(real: AccountId32, force_proxy_type: Option, call: Call),
so we need to make a proxy call with address of stash account, type of proxy call and call in encoded format like 0x0500306721211d5404bd9da88e0204360a1a9ab8b87c66c1bc2fcdd37f3c2222cc200f00a0be1c448399.
My struggle is, how do I get voting data this call data in encoded format? How do I use these imaginary keys to sign my vote?

```
const PROXY = {
               address: '5D7m1JT5QR6Pg1z4LXZPTNZqiFVzUX9NbAndeZvVzrjUCpNe',
               key: 'expose circle crack addict nasty horny men write sugar cloth sound orbit',
               type: 'Governance'
               };
const STASH = {
               address: '5Dhf5LvBWcvioXuLeGzW1xLaEKTfFmUmnE2ZC5RLKaJu2K8M',
               key: 'tank barrel crack addict nasty horny men write sugar unfold hood expect depend'
               };

       
function proxyVoting(address, type, ref_index, vote) { 
  api.tx.proxy.proxy(address, type, (call)=>{
    api.tx.democracy.vote(ref_index, vote);
  });
}
proxyVoting(STASH.address, PROXY.type, 183, true);
```

```
Error: createType(Call):: Call: failed decoding proxy.proxy:: Struct: failed on args: {"real":"AccountId32","force_proxy_type":"Option<KusamaRuntimeProxyType>","call":"Call"}:: Struct: failed on call: Call:: Call: Cannot decode value '(call)=>{
    api.tx.democracy.vote(ref_index, vote);
  }' of type function
```

Answer (score 5):

To wrap something in a proxy, just pass the `api.tx.<module>.<method>(...)` as-is.

In code it would be -

```js
function proxyVoting(address, type, ref_index, vote) { 
  return api.tx.proxy.proxy(
    address,
    'Governance',
    api.tx.democracy.vote(ref_index, vote)
  );
}
```

The same applies everywhere you need to pass a `Call` e.g. batch transactions, sudo, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the batch reference here, that helps.

Comment: Actually it's

`return api.tx.proxy.proxy(address, "Governance", api.tx.democracy.vote(ref_index, vote));`

Comment: Thank you adjusted. (Copied from above, so didn't check properly)

Answer (score 0):

A bit more comprehensive example for people struggling with this one:

```
voting = {
  "stash":"publickey of stash wallet here",
  "proxy":"secret key or pass phrase here of proxy account that has Governance right to control the stash address",
  "amount":"1 000 000 000 000",
}

let stashAccount = voting.stash;
let voteAccount = keyring.addFromUri(voting.proxy);
let balance = voting.amount;
let ref_index = 195;

let vote = {
        Standard: {
            vote: {
                aye: true,
                conviction: 'None',
            },
            balance: balance,
        }
    };

const voting = await api.tx.proxy
        .proxy(
            stashAccount,
            'Governance',
            api.tx.democracy
            .vote(
                ref_index, vote
            ),
        )
        .signAndSend(voteAccount, (result) => {
            console.log(`Status: ${result.status}`);
     });
```